# Joi alternatives not working as per required for validation of request

Tags: node.js, joi

I am using npm module `Joi` for validation of the request. 
Here my code , for which I expect error from the request, as `fooReq` is required if `invoice_number`, but Joi is returning no error.

```
let fooReq = Joi.object({
    city: Joi.string().required(),
    zip: Joi.string().required(),
}).required();

let fooOpt = Joi.object({
    city: Joi.string(),
    state: Joi.string(),
}).optional();


let barSch = {
    invoice_number: Joi.string(),
    shipping: Joi.alternatives()
        .when('invoice_number',
            {
                is: Joi.string(),
                then: fooReq,
                otherwise: fooOpt
            }
        )
};

let request = {
    invoice_number: "123"
};

console.log(Joi.validate(request, barSch));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using `when`, got from [github](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1596).

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const foo = Joi.object({
    city: Joi.string().required(),
    zip: Joi.string().required(),
});

const deliverySchema = Joi.object({
    invoice_number: Joi.string(),
    shipping: foo
        .when('invoice_number', {
            is: Joi.string().required(),
            then: Joi.required()
        })
});

console.log(deliverySchema.validate({ invoice_number: "123346575867879878" }).error)
console.log(deliverySchema.validate({}).error)
console.log(deliverySchema.validate({ shipping: 'foo' }).error)
```